# Importing a Swift protocol in Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I try to import a Swift Protocol named `AnalyticProtocol` into an Objective-C class named `AnalyticFactory`.

```
protocol AnalyticProtocol
{

}
```

**I'm starting from an existing Objective-C project (I didn't create a new Swift project with xCode and I didn't found how configure my Objective-C project to be a Swift project in xCode 6**).

In my Swift file I included the `.h` file named `MyProjectName-Swift.h` but the compiler return me an error telling me that **it doesn't exist**.
So, I created a `.h` file named `MyProjectName-Swift.h` which is actually empty (I don't know what I should put inside).

In the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77) they said that I have to include my `.h` file named `MyProjectName-Swift.h` in my `.m` file. But I need to include it not into my `.m`file but into my `.h`. Does this can be problematic?

When I try to compile I've got this error: **:0: error: xxxAnalyticFactory.h:39: cannot find protocol declaration for 'AnalyticProtocol'**

And the incriminated code:

```
@interface AnalyticFactory : NSObject
{
    Class<AnalyticProtocol> _analyticProtocolClass; // The type of the analytic class currently used.
}
```

I think I don't understand well how can I import a Swift protocol into an Objective-C class.

Does anyone see an error in what I'm doing?

Comment: Check out the [_Integrating Swift With Objective-C_](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/406xxssvkspk997/406/406_hd_integrating_swift_with_objective_c.mov?dl=1) video from WWDC 2014. At around 30:40 into the video, they describe how to access Swift protocols in Objective-C classes.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You need to add the `@objc` attribute to your Swift protocol like so:

```
@objc protocol AnalyticProtocol {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem still persists.

Comment: Could you maybe post a sample project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Adding @objc helped me with importing Swift classes in to Obj-C

Comment: @objc doesn't always work. When conforming to a protocol sometimes it doesn't work when adding the protocol on the `@interface` in the `.h` file. however, you can add the protocol to the private `@interface` in the `.m` file and it fixes things (at least it has for me on occasion). So above your `@implementation` have `@interface MyController() <AnalyticProtocol>`.

Comment: Sometimes Xcode 8 will complain while you are editing, but when you actually build it, following this answer along with the comments, the error will go away.

Comment: You also need to add `@objc` in protocol methods in order to them useable in Objective-C i.e `@objc func foo()`

Answer (score 91):

It is not possible to import the Xcode generated Swift header in objC header files.

So, since you want to use Swift code in an objC header file, you will need to "forward declare" the classes and protocols you want to use in the objC header file, like this:

```
@protocol AnalyticProtocol;
```

You can now use the protocol in your objC class declaration:

```
@interface AnalyticFactory : NSObject
{
    Class<AnalyticProtocol> _analyticProtocolClass; // The type of the analytic class currently used.
}
```

In your implementation file (the objC .m file), you can import the Xcode generated Swift header ("ProductModuleName-Swift.h") file and the correct implementation `AnalyticProtocol` will now be known to the compiler.

This is also described in official [Importing Swift into Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c)

Note that XCode will give a warning in the objC header file when you use the forward declared protocol ("Cannot find protocol definition for 'AnalyticProtocol'), but this is can be ignored - the implementation will be found at compile time.

Comment: Why does Xcode show the warning for missing protocol when it compiles and works fine? Any way to remove the warning?

Comment: It's still not possible to call the protocol methods on this class though. It will give the error ```No visible @interface for <ClassName> declares the selector <protocolMethodName>```

Comment: it produces the following warning: "Cannot find protocol definition for xxxx"

Comment: After 1.5 hours of struggle, I found this, and worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 62):

For anybody who simply needs to adopt a protocol – you can do this in two steps, without generating any warnings or errors:

1. In your `.swift` file, add `@objc` before the protocol name:

   ```
    @objc protocol AnalyticProtocol {

    }
   ```
2. In your `.m` file, import the generated Swift header and adopt the protocol in a private category. (The header file is named automagically):

   ```
    #import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"

    @interface AnalyticFactory () <AnalyticProtocol>

    @end
   ```

This is Apple’s recommended approach. You can learn more about mixing and matching Objective-C and Swift here:

[https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20170310053717/https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) (Update: Now provided via the Internet Archive.)

Comment: I still get a warning, with forward declaration or without. I'm using the protocol in an extension.

Comment: Cannot import `#import "AnalyticProtocol-Swift.h"`. Looks like that WhateverProtocol-Swift.h is not auto-generated as you said.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have updated my answer with Apple’s latest recommended approach. There are now no warnings.

Comment: This worked for me; no other suggestions or answers on this page worked. I'm on Swift 4.

Comment: This was the only way to remove the warning (even though it works when the protocols are in the header file)

Comment: IT'S NOT TRUE, recommended or not, there is other warning if you have this "fixed" class in typed array based on that protocol, compiler generates other warning, quite logically, because its not in header now.. looks like this is not possible to do warning less...

Comment: This did indeed get rid of the warning for me, but then the compile has errors, because a swift class that uses the ObjC file that adopts the Swift protocol can't see that the ObjC file is adopting the protocol!

Comment: The link is dead!

Comment: The same link is available via WebArchive:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170310053717/https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Note: If you're still getting a build warning with this approach, make sure the protocol is not forward-declared in the ObjC .h file. Additionally, you can't mark the class as conforming to the protocol in the header file. As long as the protocol appears only in .m, you'll be all set.

Comment: a possible approach to actually solve this issue using this solution is to expose a member on the class that adopts the protocol in the .h file while forward declaring the protocol.then return self in the implementaiton

Answer (score 9):

We can use swift protocols in Objective C with few changes to the code. Also, @objc declared protocols let you have optional and required methods without default implementations. It comes with pros and cons.

We could actually re-name the protocol name to a more descriptive when using in Objective C. I make use of "@objc(alias_name)".

Here is the code,
Let's have a swift protocol with @objc attribute and alias name to use in the ObjC code.

```
@objc(ObjTableViewReloadable) protocol TableViewReloadable: class {
   func reloadRow(at index: IndexPath)
   func reloadSection(at index: Int)
   func reloadTable()
}
```

Now lets farword declare our protocol in .h file

```
@protocol ObjTableViewReloadable;
```

You can now conform to this protocol in .m file and add required methods implementation.

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"
@interface MyObjcViewController () <ObjTableViewReloadable>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I'm looking at legacy code that's older than dirt and if this approach works, it will save me a ton of pain. :)

Comment: Hi, what is the header MyApp-Swift.h ? is the swift class header generated for Objc that contains the protocol?

Answer (score 5):

If your are creating a framework, the required import

```
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

changes to:

```
#import <ProductModuleName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>
```

In this case you also must make the swift protocol **public**:

```
@objc public protocol AnalyticProtocol {
  func something();
}
```