# Importing modulename-Swift.h file to ObjC .h file

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

Is it possible to import the `modulename-Swift.h` file to another `.h` file, so that the test target also would compile?

Currently, I was importing the `modulename-Swift.h` in the one of the headers of the app's target, however, the test target was not able to compile.

When I moved the import statement to the `.m` file instead, I was able to compile both, the app and the tests.

However, I have to resort to a forward protocol declaration in order to resolve this issue - the `modulename-Swift.h` file contains a protocol.

So, the question is whether I can import that file in `.h` file at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't import modulename-Swift.h in a .h file.  You'll need to create forward declarations (adding @protocol Something; to your .h) and import the Swift module in the .m file.

Another way to work around this is to declare the protocol conformance in a category in the .m file.  More details can be found in this StackOverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626493/3208043